# Microsoft Word cannot Open

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I solved my [Save problem](https://superuser.com/questions/274153/microsoft-word-cannot-save) by deleting one formula and illustration at a time to find out which one was causing the document to be corrupt, and then I redraw the offending illustration, and I could save it.

Since that day, I have worked a lot with my documents, and almost once a day, at least one file gets corrupt and I cannot save it. [I cannot believe that Word is this buggy, but apparently I am the only one using Word to write long, technical, documents, and thus the only one to see these bugs.]

Anyhow, I can live with this. I have learned to Ctrl+S once a minute, and when it fails, I simply close without saving and open the last saved version of the document, and rewrite the new material I wrote the last minute.

But now I have an even worse problem: One of my long documents won't even open!

[image: Word suddenly cannot open the document]

The dialog says, "The file %s cannot be opened since there is a problem with its content. Information: The name in the ending tag of the element has to match the element type of the starting tag. Place %s Part %s,, Row: %d,, Column %d"

The document is more than 40 pages long, and I have spent many weeks working on it. It contains a lot of formulae, illustrations, footnotes, bibliography, cross references, etc. Don't tell me I have to redo everything. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two things:

1. Try to open the document in Word with the option to repair it. In Word 2007 you have an arrow next to the Open button where you can select `Open and repair`. Word 2010 probably has the same.
2. You can try to rename .docx to .zip and then open /word/document.xml (the new Office XML files are just zip-files). Maybe you can fix the problem in the xml file yourself. Make a copy first!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I had already tried both. What's even worse is that the file size of the corrupt file is only a third (or so) of the last backup, which contains *less* text. So probably information is inevitably lost here. I 'solved' the problem by rewriting everything I had written since the last backup. Now I try to avoid problems like this by making a backup once every ten minutes, or so. I see you need some rep, so here is a 15 to get you started at SU!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the things The_Fox mentioned, I would try opening the file in OpenOffice (or LibreOffice... same thing, really). It might have more of a tolerance for imperfect files.

I would also make a backup of the file, so that it can't get any more damaged/modified.

Comment: Thanks. I would probably have tried that if it weren't for the fact that I do backup my files once a week or so, so eventually I just "solved" the problem by reverting to the last backup and rewriting everything I had written since that backup was created. Prior to this, however, I did try to open the file in WordPad, and that worked! But I only got the first few pages. And, since the file size of the corrupt file is remarkably low, maybe that is all there is in the file...

Answer (score 2):

The `Docx` converter of `Google` seems to be quite fault tolerant.

Perform the following steps:

1. Upload the file to *Google Drive*
2. Convert it to *Google Docs* format
3. Open it with *Google Docs*
4. Finally store it as `Word Docx` file.

This has just worked almost flawlessly for me!

**Note:**
Meanwhile, Microsoft [published a fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2528942/en-us) for the "missing end tag" error.
For other file corruptions, usage of third-party Word converters can be the salvation.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix these errors yourself: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2528942/en-us

See "Let me fix it myself."