# Word 2010 Equations Alter Themselves without my Approval

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2010, equations

I regularly use Microsoft Word 2010 to write long, technical documents. [One](https://superuser.com/questions/274153/microsoft-word-cannot-save) [of](https://superuser.com/questions/277425/microsoft-word-cannot-open) [many](https://superuser.com/questions/304665/word-duplicate-paragraph-bug) annoyances is that equations alter themselves without my approval. For instance, characters sometimes completely disappear. The most common issue, however, is that my vectors, which I always write in **boldface** but not in *italics*, occationally (and seemingly randomly) turns up in italics when I open a document I have previously saved. (Before I saved it, all vectors were in boldface but not in italics.)

**Before I save the document:**
[image: Before I save the document]

**When I open the document later:**
[image: When I open the document later]

Is there a known solution to this problem?

Comment: I've got similar problem! In my case Word 2010 is deleting letters from my equations. Super annoying - any way to fix it?